# Add new column in pandas dataframe with if-else conditions for existing column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add new column ( `shop_yy['tt']` )

```
for row in shop_yy['y']:
        if row > shop_yy['3sigmaM'] or row < shop_yy['3sigmaL'] :
            shop_yy['tt'] = pd.rolling_mean(shop_yy['y'],window=5)
        else:
            shop_yy['tt'] = shop_yy['y']
```

But I see this mistake:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:10: FutureWarning: pd.rolling_mean is deprecated for Series and will be removed in a future version, replace with 
    Series.rolling(center=False,window=3).mean()
  # Remove the CWD from sys.path while we load stuff.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-2d3ac684a2df> in <module>()
     13     shop_yy['3sigmaL']=shop_yy['MA'] - 3*shop_yy['std']
     14     for row in shop_yy['y']:
---> 15         if row > shop_yy['3sigmaM'] or row < shop_yy['3sigmaL'] :
     16             shop_yy['tt'] = pd.rolling_mean(shop_yy['y'],window=5)
     17         else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas-0.19.2-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
    915         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    916                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 917                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    918 
    919     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Please, help.

Answer (score 2):

The best is working with `Series`, not loop. Universal solution is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) for change values by condition:

```
m = (shop_yy['y'] > shop_yy['3sigmaM']) | (shop_yy['y'] < shop_yy['3sigmaL'])

shop_yy['tt'] = np.where(m, pd.rolling_mean(shop_yy['y'],window=5), shop_yy['y'])
```

Or:

```
shop_yy['tt'] = shop_yy['tt'].mask(m, pd.rolling_mean(shop_yy['y'],window=5))
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Thank you.

Comment: yes.it work, but I want to know how can I do it with my decision correctly. I think that problem is True/False, where I have in conditions

Comment: There is problem you compare `scalar`s with arrays - then output is array too. So if get array `[True, True, False, ...]` then if return error, because want only scalar True or False.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Like